# Are empty Obj-C methods being removed during compilation?

Tags: objective-c

Let's assume that I have a method in class like this:

```
- (void)doSomethingOnlyWhenNeeded {
    #ifdef NEEDED

    DO SOMETHING

    #endif
}
```

If I define NEEDED, everything is OK. But if NEEDED is not defined than method is empty and I want it to be removed. Is there any optimization that removes calls to such empty methods? If not, why that can be a bad idea? If yes, then do I have any control over that?

Where to find documentation on this feature?

Comment: Why do you care if the method is removed? The overhead for a few of these is completely negligible. If you have a lot of these cases, you've probably messed up the architecture of your program.

Comment: No, that's a theoretical question, not a real one. The impact is very small, of course. I wondered can I create such a class, not macro/functions, for logging purposes, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not removed during compilation, this can be a way to override a super class method, and it will stop that method being called regardless of the contents of the child classes method, this is how I am assuming the method persists with no content.

Comment: Using a C IF statement around the method as opposed to inside could remove them, then again you can't define a C constant at runtime so in that case why would you not just delete the method if you don't need it before compiling ?

Comment: I'd like to see some kind of automation here. If it's possible. Of course I can remove it or surround with some macro.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use your `#ifdef NEEDED` also when potentially calling the function?

Alternatively, you can use blocks. First you can declare the block:

```
void (^someBlock)(void);
```

And then create it if needed

```
#ifdef NEEDED

someBlock = ^{
  //do something
};

#endif
```

When calling it, you can do this:

```
if (someBlock)
  someBlock();
```

This will not call the block if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I want to simply call a method, and let compiler do it's optimization thing. Of course I can use something like this, but it'll double lines of code to type. Not so good. But thanks anyway, blocks solution is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe those will be optimized out. Now, this is not a huge concern except if called ridiculously frequently. If you're in an incredibly tight loop, then you should put the conditional around the message send rather than inside of the method.

But basically, if you haven't noticed your app running slowly and been pointed to that method by Instruments, then just do what you're doing and move on to more important coding concerns. :)

Comment: Sure, that's more like a theoretical question. How does it work and what can I do with these kind of situations? I want to understand everything and this is the question without an answer for me right now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but why don't you wrap the method itself in the preprocessor block, e.g.

```
#ifdef NEEDED
- (void)doSomethingOnlyWhenNeeded {
    DO SOMETHING
}
#endif
```

There, the method is now no longer there. :-)

Comment: That will cause errors of undefined functions during compilation with NEEDED undefined.

Comment: You specifically asked for a way to ensure that these methods wouldn't exist when `NEEDED` was undefined. Do you want the behaviour or not? :)

Comment: Yes, sure. But the solution should leave code in working state. Not break it.

Comment: If you want the method to not be there but also have the calling code not break, you have to remove the calling code too. You should move the `#ifdef` directives to the source in that case, as suggested elsewhere. Given that you didn't like that solution on account of typing, perhaps wrap the `#ifdef` and the method call itself into a macro, which you could name `MAYBE_CALL_IF_NEEDED()`.

Comment: Macro with another macro inside. I like that. :)